# Localisation of country names

Tags: sql, gettext

As part of addresses I am storing in my SQL database country codes (e.g. US, DE,...). I then have another table (with two columns) in my database which translates the country codes to the English language names of the respective countries.

If I want to make the site multi-language, I could expand this translation table adding country names in other languages than English.

I was wondering if there is another method which does not involve modification of the database, e.g. using gettext to translate the English country names?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to handle this is to change the table structure to have three columns, instead of two:

- Language
- CounryCode
- FullName

Whenever you query the database, you would provide the current language.

You then have to change your code to include the additional language key in any queries.

Depending on how you are going to keep track of the current language, you would also use a view or user defined function.

You don't want to use automated translation, since the name of a country like "China" could turn into the equivalent of "porcelain".

Comment: Not sure I understand. Where would the full country name in say Icelandic appear then? I was thinking of three columns like: CountryCode, FullNameEnglish, FullNameIcelandic and then to extract either the 2nd or 3rd column depending on the chosen language.